# adding a 2nd transform on hover

Tags: css, sass, hover

I have an icon font (built in icomoon) that I display flipped in the y-axis using FontAwesome's helper class .fa-flip-vertical

```
.icon-reject-outline {
    @extend .icon-approve;
    @extend .fa-flip-vertical;
}
```

I want to grow it 40% on hover, however the way SASS extends classes, just selecting on .fa-flip-vertical doesn't work, I'll need to remember to extend my .hover-grow class to include every icon that is flipped, otherwise the 40% grow transform overwrites the flip transform rather than adding to it:

```
.x-action-column-hover-grow .x-action-col-icon {
    transition: scale .2s ease-in-out;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    &:hover {
        transform: scale(1.4);
    }
    &.fa-flip-vertical:hover,&.icon-reject-outline:hover{ // I'd ideally not need the second selector here
        transform: scale(1.4) scaleY(-1)
    }
}
```

This feels a bit yucky, so I was wondering whether there was a way to flag classes extending .fa-flip-vertical so that the &hover knows to keep it flipped or somehow make the &hover transform be additive rather than replacing the non-hover transform.

I don't think it's relevant to the answer, but this is using ExtJS 6.2

For completeness, `.fa-flip-vertical` is defined as follows:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2, mirror=1)";
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, -1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, -1);
    transform: scale(1, -1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that in CSS: an overridden property is overridden and previous value is lost.

In Sass, a way to do it would be to use a mixin:

```
@mixin transform-and-flip($val) {
  transform: $val scaleY(-1);
}

$make-the-logo-bigger: scale(1.4);

.x-action-column-hover-grow .x-action-col-icon {
  transition: scale .2s ease-in-out;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;

  &:hover {
    transform: $make-the-logo-bigger;
  }

  &.fa-flip-vertical:hover,
  &.icon-reject-outline:hover {
    @include transform-and-flip($make-the-logo-bigger);
  }
}
```

For blocks, I'd use the **[`@content` directive](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sasss-content-directive)**. If I'd to play frequently with complicated multi-backgrounds or box-shadows or linear-gradients